# Core data deleted items are visible even after delete (till app relaunches)

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I am having a many to many relationship between two tables say table A and B.

For the sake of business logic I have put this property with 'No Action' as deletion rule.

step 1: Now at a point I am deleting table A items.

step 2: After deletion of tableA items I want to delete those items in Table B which are not connected with any item in table A.

so the code snippet for deletion for step 2 is somewhat like this:

```
for (TableBItem* item in fetchedObjects) {
    if ([[item.tableAproperty allObjects] count] == 0) {
        [context deleteObject:item];
    }
} 
 //save context
 [context save:&error]
```

After this when i am fetching tableB objects it shows me even those items which i tried to delete.

If I kill the application and launch again then the fetching items works as expected.

Any idea what might be going wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your context architecture? did the save succeeded?

Comment: I am using normal NSManagedObjectContext, yes save did succeed with no error.

Answer (score 1):

A proven method to accomplish this is to override the remove object Xcode-generated setter method in your managed object subclass for `TableBItem` (a terrible name BTW - also, `tableAProperty` is misleading as it is a relationship and not an attribute).

```
-(void)removeTableAPropertyObject:(TableAItem *)value {
     [super removeTableAPropertyObject:value];
     if (!self.tableAProperty.count) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
     }
}
```

Comment: Good faith answer, comment-less down vote. Thank you very much. I am using this pattern frequently with no errors.

Comment: Agree with @Mundi. In addition downvote without comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is to set the delete rule to 'nullfiy'. This way, deleting an entity A will nullify the relation from B to A. Hence, no B will be linked to A after deleting all A's.
I can't really give you an explanation about the difference after re-launch, I guess some staleness or cache/faulting effects.

Comment: Problem with nullify property is that B is linked to multiple A items, deleting any item in A will nullify B's item, which i don't want. I want to delete the B item only when it is not linked with any of A.

Comment: Ah I see. Depending on performance, the easiest thing would be to implement the prepareFoDeletionMethod. In this method, check the other end of the relationship, see if youbare / were the last relation and then also delete is. This will only work well on not too mang or not too often occutances. See the dics on NSManagedObject: Discussion
You can implement this method to perform any operations required before the object is deleted, such as custom propagation before relationships are torn down, or reconfiguration of objects using key-value observing.